# Azure Storage V2 blob event - Not triggering ADF

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-eventgrid

I have an Azure Data Factory V2 (X), with a blob event trigger. The blob event trigger works fine and triggers the Data Facotry (X) when I manually upload a file using the storage explorer. But when I use another data factory (Y) to write the file to the same Blob Storage instead of manual write,  the event doesn't trigger my Data Factory (X).

I have verified the following:

1. There are no multiple events under the 'Events' blade section of the Blob Storage.
2. There is a System Topic and a Subscription created with the correct filters. I have the 'BeginsWith' with my container name and  'EndsWith' with the file extension 'parquet'.
3. I have verified the related questions on Stack Overflow but this seems to be different.

Any clues what could be wrong or is this a known issue?

EDIT:
I checked the logs of the Event Topic & Subscription, when the file is written by the ADF (Y) there is no event generated but with the manual upload/write the event gets triggered.

Comment: The 'event created' is basiclly based on the new etag of blob. So if you really send blob, new etag will appear, and then the event trigger will be triggered. Try to dont set the beginwith and endwith and check whether the problem still exists.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, I used synapse notebook.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/issues/30780

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue writing CSV data from an application using Azure SDK. **I observed that the Storage Events trigger wasn't firing when the application wrote to ADLSG2, but when I manually uploaded the file, the trigger fired.**

I compared the properties of the files written by the application and the file I manually uploaded to ADLS and discovered their *CONTENT-TYPE* properties differed. The file created by the application was an ***application/octet-stream***, while the file I uploaded was a ***text/csv***. Since the application's data was written as a stream, it starts with ***"0 bytes and file size grows until all the data is written permanently"***; consequently, if you created the trigger to **"Ignore empty blobs"**, the file is actually empty at the first instance, and so ignored.

**I solved this issue by setting "Ignore empty blobs" to No when creating the trigger.**

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If your event of trigger is blob created, then the blob event trigger is basically depends on the new Etag. When the new etag is created, then your pipeline will be triggered.

This is the trigger on my side:

[image]

On my side, I create 3 containers: test1,test2,test3. Pipeline on Datafactory Y send files from test1 to test2, and pipeline on Datafactory X have above trigger. If triggered, it will send files from test2 to test3. When file is writed by the pipeline on Datafactory Y, pipeline on Datafactory X will be triggered. And files will be send to test3 with no problem.

Basiclly, the principle of the 'blob created' is based on the new etag of your container. When your Datafactory send files to target container, then there is no doubt that a new etag will appear.

I notice you mentioned the BeginsWith and EndsWith, so I think this is the problem comes from. Please have a check of that.