# Azure ADF Pipeline Copy-Data Log Files not firing 2nd Pipeline's "Blob Created" Trigger

Tags: logging, triggers, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-factory

Using Azure Data Factory V2
I have 2 piplelines. One that reads CSV data files uploaded to a blob storage container & processes the data. That pipeline is triggered by "Blob Created".
I have set up "Warning" Level Logging for pipeline 1 to catch data errors, missing column headers, extra (un-mapped) columns, and I created the destination folder to store those log files called 'file-data-errors'.
That all works. The 'file-data-errors' container is being populated with *.txt files as expected.

I want to populate an Azure SQL Table with the contents of the CSV files.
To do that I set up another pipeline with a trigger that fires on "Blob Created" when a file is added to the 'file-data-errors' container.

To test the 2nd pipleline, I upload a file (one earlier created by pipeline 1) to the 'file-data-errors' container, the process succeeds.

But when I upload a file to the blob storage of the first pipeline, the second pipeline does not get triggered as expected. That is, a file is added to the 'file-data-errors' container as normal, but the "Blob Created" trigger doesn't fire.

I have found a very similar question on stackoverflow,
[Azure Storage V2 blob event - Not triggering ADF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62776392/azure-storage-v2-blob-event-not-triggering-adf)
but the suggested solution does not work for me

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you published the second trigger?

Comment: Yes, both triggers are published. 
By changing the 2nd trigger to a schedule instead of the blob created event, I got it working. The 2nd pipleline only needs to run daily anyway, so this is working OK  now

Comment: Glad to hear it works. You can post an answer to end this question. It will be benefit to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Just post an answer to end this question.

Solution:

> By changing the 2nd trigger to a schedule instead of the blob created
> event, I got it working. The 2nd pipleline only needs to run daily
> anyway, so this is working OK now